# comparing datapoints in an Array

Tags: c, optimization

I would like to compare 3 datapoints in one struct Array.
in an manner resembling this:

```
Example: In an Array[4] 
X...Datapoints which should be compared

XXXO
XXOX
XOXX
OXXX
```

.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
  for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++){
   if( i != j && j != k && k != i ){    // prohibits sets of 111 223 ...
    if( isSET(array[a], array[b], array[c]) == 1 ){
      Tset[n].a = a;
      Tset[n].b = b;
      Tset[n].c = c;
      n++;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

if I run the code I would get 6 sets of the same set.
e.g.

```
a b c
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1

but I only need one of those.
```

Is there a good way to do this?

I'm sorry for the bad asking.

Comment: `break` the loop as soon as you receive one set?

Comment: Iterate `i` for 0 <= `i` < 12, as you do, then iterate `j` for 0 <= `j` < `i` and `k` for 0 <= `k` < `j`.

Comment: You do realize `==` is the comparison operation, not the set operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12-2; i++){
 for (int j = i+1; j < 12-1; j++){
  for (int k = j+1; k < 12; k++){
    if( isSET(array[i], array[j], array[k]) == 1 ){
      set[n].a = i;
      set[n].b = j;
      set[n].c = k;
      n++;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's good that you've posted this as the answer, but it would be even better if you now edited your question to remove the answer you posted there, and then mark this as accepted by clicking the green outline check mark next to the anwer.